# Turn a comic strip to an iPhone webapp

Tags: javascript, ios, iphone, swipe

I am helping a friend to turn her weekly comic strip into an iPhone webapp.  Is there any sample app that I can learn how this is done?

The comic strip is a new jpeg file every week, usually containing 4 blocks.  It is desirable to show one block at a time and use swipe events to move back and forth.

Any help is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should check out the jQtouch library. It's designed to support phone gestures for webapps:
http://www.jqtouch.com/

In particular, the beta version has swipe detection:
https://github.com/senchalabs/jQTouch/wiki/Callback-Events